# Ideas how to get a div to appear if AJAX request takes longer then x-ms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that I need executed every couple seconds, generally the call take about 25ms, but from time to time (maybe 10%) the call can take between 300ms and 900ms, What I wanted to do is if more then say... 250ms elapses, for a div to be shown basicly saying "loading", that will disappear on the success of the AJAX query.  Is such a thing possible? if so, how complex would an addition like that be?

If it helps, here is my current AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "../PHP/mapParse.php",
      data: {   account: sessionStorage.account,
                direction: dir},
      success: generateMap,
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use window.setTimeout to set a timeout after the desired delay. Set the timeout right before the $.ajax line, and save the timeoutId in a local variable. In the timeout handler, display your div.

When the ajax call completes, either cancel the timeout, hide the div, or both. You can cancel a timeout with window.clearTimeout, passing the timeoutId saved previously.

Comment: Note: You shouldn't do this on $.ajax success. Success callbacks are only called if the request is successful. Instead use the returned deferred object and cancel the loading message on either "always" or "done" so all bases are covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a delayed call to show the loading box after 250ms. Then in the ajax callback, cancel the delayed call, and hide the loading box if it's already showing.

CSS:

```
div.loading-box
{
  /* whatever loading box styles here */
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var loading = window.setTimeout(showLoadingBox,250);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "../PHP/mapParse.php",
  data: {   account: sessionStorage.account,
            direction: dir},
  success: function() {cancelLoadingBox();generateMap();},
});

function showLoadingBox() {
  $('.loading-box').show();
}

function cancelLoadingBox() {
  window.clearTimeout(loading);
  $('.loading-box').hide();
}
```